# Python 3 can't find setuptools module - Ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, ubuntu, setuptools

I forked a Github repo and am struggling to compile the project. I am using Ubuntu and am trying to install using the setup.py file but I get this:

```
$sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  python3-setuptools is already the newest version (20.7.0-1)
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 100 not upgraded.
$python3 setup.py install
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
      from setuptools import setup, find_packages
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

I've also tried compiling with python 2. I used `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` and then when I try `python setup.py install` I get an issue that I think means that the code I am trying to compile is python 3 code. The issue is

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pokemon_terminal-0.0.1-py2.7.egg/pokemonterminal/database.py", line 101
def get_pokemon_of_type(self, pkmn_type: str, single: bool = True):
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running this in an Ubuntu terminal. I was wondering if anyone had any insight on my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a virtual enviroment will fix this.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
... do whatever you need to do.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the module straight from the code itself.

```
try:
    import setuptools
except:
    import os
    os.system("pip install setuptools")
    del os
```

Comment: It looks like it still couldn't use setuptools: It installs setuptools but then can't find the setup() method, which I assume is in setuptools
`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recompiling my Python 3 and it installed the newest version of pip and setuptools and worked. Problem solved!